# Datetime values returned as double values when converting an xlsx file to csv using apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have an excel(xlsx) file that has datetime values along with other datatypes. When I use apache POI to convert the file to csv, the datetimes are returned as double values in the csv.
The format of the datetime values is a custom one `[$-409]dd\ mmm\ yyyy;@`
The other standard format values like dd/mm/yy are parsed correctly but this custome one is parsed incorrectly.

I have used both eventmodel and usermodel implementations but both are not working. How can I proceed with this?

Comment: What code are you using to do the formatting of values into the CSV? Without seeing that, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong...

Comment: All date/time values are stored in Excel as floating point values. The integer portion represents the day (from Jan 1, 1900). The decimal portion equates to the percentage of 24 hours in a day. [This website](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time) gives a good explanation. If you want to specifically save your time as dd/mmm/yyyy then you'll have to explicitly convert the floating point number to a text string, and then export to CSV.

Comment: Use https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html - it can take a Cell and provide you with the formatted text that should match what Excel displays for that cell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.